# Objective c- Is it possible to do animation without using the GPU?

Tags: iphone, ios, object, core-animation

Is it possible to do animations and force it to be done in the CPU instead of in the GPU?

I'll try to explain my motivation, one of my screens as a large view that do a lot of GPU work, I also have few button and controllers that suppose to do animations like slide from side to side when tapped..

The problem is, in some older devices such as iPod, the button animation is really slow (I suppose because all the GPU power is used for my main view).
So I though, maybe there is a way to force the animation to be done in the CPU instead?

Comment: I doubt that is the reason.  It probably has more to do with the CPU being dual core or not.  Have you ever used 3D mark?  It has a CPU rendering mode which tries to render really simple polygons at around 1 frame per second.  The **last** thing you want to do is try to attempt animation calculations on the CPU.

Comment: What @borrrden said and also note that GPU rendering does not entirely free the CPU for other stuff. GPU and CPU have to wait for each other constantly for exchanging data.

Comment: hi @borrrden, my main view is doing photo filtering (using GPUImage lib) that uses the GPU, so I thought it was the reason.. can you see a solution for this problem?

Comment: The only thing you can do is make sure you are making use of async operations and grand central dispatch to free up the main thread more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

In Mac OS and iOS, the GPU is responsible for rendering graphics onto the display.

Any CPU-based animation will ultimately still make use of the GPU in order to render the contents to the screen. The underlying graphics engine is OpenGL.

On iOS, Core Animation layers map directly to display tiles in the graphics hardware.

Trying to do purely CPU-based graphics might even backfire, because you end up having to render every frame on the CPU, and then still copy those pixels into GPU memory.